# the content of sequence must match the (annotation?,(element,group,choice, sequence any)*).A problem was found starting at:attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

My XML:

Suruthi
Packing
CHP02
JPP03
200 kg
08/08/2017




Gayathri
Sales
JPP02
INP04
1000 kg
03/07/2017




Pranesh
Packing
CHP02
JPP01
100 kg
08/08/2017




Swaathi
Packing
JPP02
INP02
200 kg
08/08/2017




Santhosh
Packing
CHP03
INP02
200 kg
18/09/2017




Raj
Packing
CHP04
INP02
200 kg
08/08/2017




Karthika
Packing
CHP04
JPP03
200 kg
20/08/2017




Priya
Packing
CHP04
INP01
200 kg
20/08/2017




Praveen
Packing
CHP04
JPP02
200 kg
18/09/2017




Rathish
Packing
CHP04
INP03
200 kg
18/09/2017

Schema:

```
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.DATAX.com/XML" xmlns="http://www.DATAX.com/XMLSchema/Shipment" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:element name="shipments">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="shipment" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer"/>
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:all>
                                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="department" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="departurePortId" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="arrivalPortId" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="weight" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="shipmentDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="string" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/> 
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:all>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
         </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: The XML that you posted is not valid. It should be in a code block (like the XSD). Please edit your question and fix both problems.